# finding nearest collider in one collision

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 2 barrels in one Room side by side . I give my Player a Sphere Collider in front of him. So if he detected a Collision, the my player takes a sphere to the collision position (for example one of these barrel). My question is, how could be detected the nearest barrel, if they are in these Player Sphere Collider. Anouther question is, that the warning sound is not playing

Comment: Show what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

void OnCollisionEnter(UnityEngine.Collision collision)
    {

```
    ContactPoint contact = collision.contacts[0];


    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Untagged")

    {
        return;
    }
    Vector3 pos = contact.point;

    roteKugel.transform.position = pos;

    audioSource.Play();
```

}

This is what i have. So the sound is playing, when i enter a collision. But i cant find the nearest Object in this Collision. Also sometimes the sound stops, when I go near to the collision object.  Is there a function to do that? If I put the the sound into the OnCollisionStay method, the sound is going crazy (plays every frame).